# View actions multiply when resetting perspective

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I have a problem with an rcp application regarding view actions. Whenever I reset my perspective, the selected view part(if it is not the first one from the stack) multiplies its actions.

My view actions are added in plugin.xml extensions accordingly, and the view parts react the same even if I add them from plugin.xml extensions or folderLayouts in perspectives.

---

Before reset: 
[image: Before reset]

After reset: 
[image: After reset] => extra set of actions

If I would reset again, there would be 3 sets of actions.

---

Notes:

- To reproduce you must focus on a view part from a stack and reset perspective
- This cannot be reproduced by focusing on first view part of the stack(it will never multiply its actions)

---

Has anyone else encountered this problem or has any idea what could possibly be wrong?

Thank you in advance!